# GetStream-IO - Dynamic Content With Realtime data

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I am trying to figure out the best approach to storing data in get-stream, and how to pull real-time data on the client-side.

For example, let's say I have a user and they have an image. When they create a post, I add an activity:

```
const eventStreamPromise = eventStream.addActivity({
  actor: event,
  verb: 'post',
  object: postId,
  foreign_id: postId,
  postText: 'some text',
  user: 'internalUserId',
});
```

I would  think I would use just a reference to the user, which is fine for when I do an initial load on the feed (I pull the feed from the client-side). But then, I'm not sure of the best way to get this data when I subscribe to the feed on the client-side.

```
this.getStreamListener = feed
  .subscribe((data) {
    console.log(data, 'got feed data, now what?');
  })
  .then(() {
    console.log('now listening to changes in realtime');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function that is passed to the `subscribe()` method is invoked on every realtime update. The data parameter that's passed contains the activity along with some additional metadata like the timestamp.

Within that 'callback' function you can read the fields, e.g. the 'user' id, pull data from your back-end, update your client, etc.

Hopefully that helps?

Comment: It seems like a lot of latency... After reading the documents more, I realize that get-stream using the term "enrich". I basically want to "enrich" the real-time data.

Comment: You're correct that there is additional work to enrich the activities. It really depends on the specific use-case but for most applications the enrichment step isn't a significant factor. If you happen to raise another SO question that asks about the best practices for your situation, I'll happily try to respond.

Comment: I think Im going to just leave realtime to notifications for now. Thanks Dwight!